# How to remove stutter when scrolling view with finger in Android?

Tags: android, scroll, smooth-scrolling

So, I have a ViewGroup (A) that I scroll up and down and it works great.  But, I have another view (B) that should expand/collapse as the other view scrolls down/up.

Right now, if I scroll towards the top of (A), then (B) should expand until it all of its content is visible.  If I scroll (A) towards the bottom, then (B) should collapse and remain collapsed until (A) is scrolled back close enough to its top to expand (B) again.

I have a working prototype that achieves the basic effect.  If I scroll fast enough either direction, it looks great.  BUT, I'm seeing a lot of jumping/stuttering if my finger remains relatively still.  It seems to be b/c my finger naturally isn't perfectly still, so I get some back and forth (negative/positive) scroll values (which makes sense).

Can someone point me to some articles or algorithms that'll help smooth out such fluctuations and avoid the jumping/stuttering?  I've done a lot of Google searching, but haven't found anything yet.

Environment:
Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5
Android 4.1+
Testing on Nexus 5X + Marshmallow